# C++ return statement strange behaviour?

Tags: c++

I've discovered something new (for myself) about `return` statements. In combination with `for` and `if` this force debugger to not return control from function and proceed to the next statements, instead, it stacks inside function and repeat `for` until condition will not be true. For example:

```
struct Position
{
    int position;
    int value;
};

vector<Position> find_all(vector<Position>& v, int value)
{
    vector<Position> res;
    for (auto p = v.begin(); p != v.end(); ++p)
        if (p->value == value)
            res.push_back(*p);

    return res;
}

int main()
{
    vector<Position> v { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 0 }, { 3, 3 },
                         { 4, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 6, 0 }, { 7, 2 } };
    find_all(v, 0); 
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

If you set debugger to `return res;` and start debugging code, when you step into this method the function will continue executes inside function until for loop ends, instead return. If you set curly brackets in `if` statements return will work normal.

I do not understand please someone explain me what happens and why? Im using `VisualC++` but found this type of `return` usage in Stroustrup book.

Comment: "*If you set curly brackets in "if" statements return will work normal.*" - Can you show this code please?

Comment: That is probably a "feature" of your IDE/Debugger. It certainly isn't something to do with the C++ language.

Comment: &Maroun Maroun vector<Position> find_all(vector<Position>& v, int value)
{
    vector<Position> res;
    for (auto p = v.begin(); p != v.end(); ++p)
        if (p->value == value){
        res.push_back(*p);
}
    return res;
}

Comment: In this case the codes are **exactly** the same. There is something else happening there..

Comment: Not the same - curly braces after if (p->value == value) removes this strange behaviour but if you not set it, the code above will not immediatly return from function to next statements.

Comment: if curly bracket were placed like @Marou Marou said, that function should be call "Find_First" !!!

Comment: @ChaosDev: Hehehe! You are seeing that behavior because your IDE (Visual Studio) interprets IP register values and source code line numbers that way. You can put almost anything else in place of that `return` and it will behave that way. So, don't worry. It's the *debugger* that's behaving strangely, and you are miles away (I'm only guessing here) from understanding how debuggers work.

Comment: @yzt Tell me more please. Do you see this feature in your IDE too?

Comment: @ChaosDev: Of course. This is the way Visual Studio behaves while debugging loops. But note that it's not always so; simple stuff like adding curly braces and the like will change this behavior. This is simply a "feature" of VS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is symptomatic of source-level debugger trying to track execution of machine code back to the source code. The `for` loop has a condition `p != v.end()` which is actually a `while` condition and is evaluated at each iteration. This condition evaluation is typically at the end of the loop (in MSVC at least). In your example, there is no code at the end of the loop, so the debugger shows the "current line" as the statement after the loop, which is the `return res;` line.

If you put curly braces around the `for` loop body, with the closing curly on a new line, then the debugger will have a line of code to associate with the condition, and you will see expected behavior.

```
vector<Position> find_all(vector<Position>& v, int value)
{
    vector<Position> res;
    for (auto p = v.begin(); p != v.end(); ++p)
    {
        if (p->value == value)
            res.push_back(*p);
    }

    return res;
}
```

Remember that the debugger shows an approximation of the current line. In Debug mode, this is usually pretty accurate, but there are cases such as this where it "looks odd". If you try stepping through a Release build, with optimizations, you'll notice the "current line" appears to jump around all over.